# Nginx redirect to https

Tags: http, nginx

THis is the block i need to redirect to `https`:

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html?$query_string;
}
```

Is there any way to simply forward this to `https`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name                 example.com;
    location / {
        rewrite                 ^(.*)$  https://example.com$1  permanent;
    }
}
```